# Create PHP session when mouse moved at least once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to create php session when mouse is moved at least once then no need to do anything if mouse keeps moving

I am using this code but its not solving the requirement

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
   $(document).mousemove(function(e)
   {
      $('#status').html(e.pageX);
      $('#status1').html(e.pageY);
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'second.php',
        data: { 
            'x': '10', 
            'y': '20' 
        },
        success: function(msg){
            //what you want after request
        }
    });
  });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Use isset with session name in server side and if already set then do not set it again.

Comment: don't do that; you'll be firing a lot of xhr requests... just register client side if a new session start needs to happen. Something like `var mousemove = true; if ( $mousemove === true ) { // do not send another request }`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The PHP code should be something like this:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['mouseMoved'])
    $_SESSION['mouseMoved'] = "whatever you want";
```

Also, you should set some variable in JS so that the request is only sent to the server once.

Updated: a working jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bqh0yrtp/

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser console? I've updated my answer with a working fiddle, the event fires when mouse moves. Make sure you have included the jQuery library.